# Unable to access /api/xmlrpc/ without "index.php"

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I wish to access the Magento API via XML-RPC (without the "index.php").

If I tried the http://magento.url/index.php/api/xmlrpc, there would be a XML response.

```
<methodResponse>
<fault>
<value>
<struct>
<member>
<name>faultCode</name>
<value>
<int>630</int>
</value>
</member>
<member>
<name>faultString</name>
<value>
<string>Unable to read request</string>
</value>
</member>
</struct>
</value>
</fault>
</methodResponse>
```

Sorry for the indentation.

However, if I tried with http://magento.url/api/xmlrpc, I would get "NOT FOUND" error in return. 
May I know how can I resolve this "index.php" issue? T

Thank you.

Comment: This is a sign that it is working if you are accessing it via the browser. You need to do a POST to that page to get relevant information.